# Why doesn't my AsyncTask stop?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to upload a photo to my FTP Server and it is going alright, but my AsyncTask doesn't finish. My logs show that everything went correctly. Whats going on?
Here is my code:

```
  public class LoadPerfil extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Perfil.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Carregando informações...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        //we will develop this method in version 2
        updateJSONdata();
        return null;

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(nome);
        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).
        load("http://gargsolutions.com.br/budge_backend/fotos/"+id+".jpg")
        .resize(200, 260)
        .centerCrop()
        .into(FotoPerfil);
        txtBiografia.setText(biografia);
        txtPontos.setText("Pontuação: "+String.valueOf(pontuacao));
        pDialog.dismiss();
      //we will develop this method in version 2



    }
}    

public class UploadFoto extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Perfil.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Upando foto...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        //we will develop this method in version 2
          upaFoto();
        //upaMetodo2();

        return null;

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
      new LoadPerfil().execute();
      //we will develop this method in version 2
      pDialog.dismiss();


    }
}    

public void upaFoto(){

      FTPClient con = null;

      try
      {
          con = new FTPClient();
          con.connect("xxx");
          Log.i("ta chegando aqui", "antes do if de login");
          if (con.login("xx", "glaxxrgx"))
          {    
              Log.i("teste", "logou ftp");
              con.enterLocalPassiveMode(); // important!
              con.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
              String data1 = diretorio+"/"+id+".jpg";
              Log.i("teste", data1);

              FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(data1));
              boolean result = con.storeFile("/www/budge_backend/fotos/"+id+".jpg", in);
              in.close();
              if (result) Log.i("upload result", "succeeded");
              con.logout();
              con.disconnect();
          }
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
          Log.i("erro ao logar", e.toString());
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
}
public void updateJSONdata(){

// Instantiate the arraylist to contain all the JSON data.
// we are going to use a bunch of key-value pairs, referring
// to the json element name, and the content, for example,
// message it the tag, and "I'm awesome" as the content..

mPerfilLists = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

// Bro, it's time to power up the J parser 
JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
// Feed the beast our comments url, and it spits us
//back a JSON object.  Boo-yeah Jerome.
LoadPrefs();
JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(LER_LOCAL_URL+"?email="+email);
Log.i("teste url", LER_LOCAL_URL+"?email="+email);

//when parsing JSON stuff, we should probably
//try to catch any exceptions:
try {

    //I know I said we would check if "Posts were Avail." (success==1)
    //before we tried to read the individual posts, but I lied...
    //mComments will tell us how many "posts" or comments are
    //available
    mPerfil = json.getJSONArray(TAG_POSTS);  
    // looping through all posts according to the json object returned
    for (int i = 0; i < mPerfil.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject c = mPerfil.getJSONObject(i);

        //gets the content of each tag
         nome = c.getString("nome");
         biografia = c.getString("biografia");
         pontuacao = c.getInt("pontuacao");
         id = c.getString("id");
        //String comentarios =  c.getString("coments");
        //String message = c.getString("sucess");
         Log.i("testando resultados: ", nome+biografia+pontuacao);


      // map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        //.position(new LatLng(lati, longi))
        //.title(linha)
        //.snippet(usuario));


        //annndddd, our JSON data is up to date same with our array list
    }

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    Log.i("try/catch", "Ta caindo no cacth");
   // resultado = 1;
}
 }

  @Override
    protected void onResume() {
       super.onResume();
       new LoadPerfil().execute();
   }
```

EDIT:

My logs results, you can see, "upload succeded", "do in back...", "on post":

```
11-19 18:25:41.192: I/teste url(2183): http://gargsolutions.com.br/budge_backend/perfil.php?email=Gabrielmalinosqui@gmail.com
11-19 18:25:41.192: I/testando resultados:(2183): Gabriel Jacomini Malinosqui18 anos, CEO at GARG Solutions, UNIP Ciência da Computação0
11-19 18:25:41.282: W/IMGSRV(2183): :0: gralloc_unregister_buffer: ID: 28956 handle: 0x56f3abf0 size: 513 x 144 fmt: 5 usage: 0xb00
11-19 18:25:41.282: W/IMGSRV(2183): :0: gralloc_unregister_buffer: ID: 28958 handle: 0x57324a20 size: 513 x 144 fmt: 5 usage: 0xb00
11-19 18:25:41.282: W/IMGSRV(2183): :0: gralloc_unregister_buffer: ID: 28961 handle: 0x5691b870 size: 513 x 144 fmt: 5 usage: 0xb00
11-19 18:25:41.412: W/IMGSRV(2183): :0: gralloc_unregister_buffer: ID: 28949 handle: 0x57224d00 size: 540 x 778 fmt: 511 usage: 0x300
11-19 18:25:42.292: W/IMGSRV(2183): :0: gralloc_unregister_buffer: ID: 28951 handle: 0x573aa2b0 size: 480 x 205 fmt: 1 usage: 0x933
11-19 18:25:44.482: W/IMGSRV(2183): :0: gralloc_unregister_buffer: ID: 28957 handle: 0x56f302b0 size: 540 x 888 fmt: 5 usage: 0xb00
11-19 18:25:44.482: W/IMGSRV(2183): :0: gralloc_unregister_buffer: ID: 28959 handle: 0x54e09450 size: 540 x 888 fmt: 5 usage: 0xb00
11-19 18:25:44.482: W/IMGSRV(2183): :0: gralloc_unregister_buffer: ID: 28960 handle: 0x57220de0 size: 540 x 888 fmt: 5 usage: 0xb00
11-19 18:25:51.632: I/Teste arquivo(2183): /storage/sdcard0/BusaoBauru/62.jpg
11-19 18:25:52.242: W/IMGSRV(2183): :0: gralloc_register_buffer: ID: 28974 handle: 0x5694a510 size: 513 x 144 fmt: 5 usage: 0xb00
11-19 18:25:52.292: W/IMGSRV(2183): :0: gralloc_register_buffer: ID: 28975 handle: 0x52f24e30 size: 540 x 888 fmt: 5 usage: 0xb00
11-19 18:25:52.312: W/IMGSRV(2183): :0: gralloc_register_buffer: ID: 28976 handle: 0x52f5df60 size: 513 x 144 fmt: 5 usage: 0xb00
11-19 18:25:52.472: W/IMGSRV(2183): :0: gralloc_register_buffer: ID: 28977 handle: 0x56d144c0 size: 513 x 144 fmt: 5 usage: 0xb00
11-19 18:25:52.582: W/IMGSRV(2183): :0: gralloc_register_buffer: ID: 28978 handle: 0x5798c6b0 size: 540 x 888 fmt: 5 usage: 0xb00
11-19 18:25:52.602: W/IMGSRV(2183): :0: gralloc_register_buffer: ID: 28979 handle: 0x54e01b80 size: 513 x 144 fmt: 5 usage: 0xb00
11-19 18:25:52.632: W/IMGSRV(2183): :0: gralloc_register_buffer: ID: 28980 handle: 0x52f5eac0 size: 513 x 144 fmt: 5 usage: 0xb00
11-19 18:25:52.662: W/IMGSRV(2183): :0: gralloc_register_buffer: ID: 28981 handle: 0x55656e10 size: 513 x 144 fmt: 5 usage: 0xb00
11-19 18:25:52.962: I/ta chegando aqui(2183): antes do if de login
11-19 18:25:53.392: I/teste(2183): logou ftp
11-19 18:25:53.522: W/IMGSRV(2183): :0: gralloc_register_buffer: ID: 28982 handle: 0x56d136d0 size: 540 x 888 fmt: 5 usage: 0xb00
11-19 18:25:53.582: I/teste(2183): /storage/sdcard0/BusaoBauru/62.jpg
11-19 18:25:55.152: I/upload result(2183): succeeded
11-19 18:25:55.472: I/teste(2183): do in back...
11-19 18:25:55.542: I/teste(2183): On post..
11-19 18:25:55.582: W/IMGSRV(2183): :0: gralloc_unregister_buffer: ID: 28976 handle: 0x52f5df60 size: 513 x 144 fmt: 5 usage: 0xb00
11-19 18:25:55.582: W/IMGSRV(2183): :0: gralloc_unregister_buffer: ID: 28979 handle: 0x54e01b80 size: 513 x 144 fmt: 5 usage: 0xb00
11-19 18:25:55.582: W/IMGSRV(2183): :0: gralloc_unregister_buffer: ID: 28981 handle: 0x55656e10 size: 513 x 144 fmt: 5 usage: 0xb00
11-19 18:25:56.162: I/teste url(2183): http://gargsolutions.com.br/budge_backend/perfil.php?email=Gabrielmalinosqui@gmail.com
11-19 18:25:56.162: I/testando resultados:(2183): Gabriel Jacomini Malinosqui18 anos, CEO at GARG Solutions, UNIP Ciência da Computação0
```

Comment: Why is your doInBackground returning null instead of a boolean? Also, is your onPostExecute getting called?

Comment: Why do you call super.* in your async tasks? Those aren't necessary.

Comment: "srry for my bad english, and my bad code indentation" - You can fix your code indentation yourself pretty easily, and it would demonstrate that you are serious about helping us help you.

Comment: Which task doesn't complete? `UploadFoto`, or the `LoadPerfil` that gets called from it? These logs that you say show everything working, can we see them?

Comment: @ Eddy K I change to "return true", nothing, and i dont understand your second question, sorry.

Comment: Giobits, the UploadFoto Task.

Comment: One thing for sure, you shouldn't dismiss your dialog from `doInBackground()`. Dismiss it from `onPostExecute()` instead, since it runs on the UI thread. Can't promise it's what's causing your problem, but it needs to be changed either way.

Comment: Geobits, I corrected it, but not had effect.

Comment: Where did you decklare pDialog variable

Comment: In my main class, its a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is most likely due to confusion surrounding what the cancel method of AsyncTask actually does. Basically you need to break down your background task into loopable segments, then before each loop iteration starts doing your task you need to check if the task is cancelled, then if it is you need to break the loop. There doesn't seem to be any other way to stop an AsyncTask from executing.

I've posted a detailed guide to this problem with code examples here:

http://tpbapp.com/android-development/android-asynctask-stop-running-cancel-method/